# Laravel 5.4 Route::post() NotFoundException

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

Hi I have a problem with Laravel 5.4 routes, Route::get() are working but Route::post() give me NotFoundException error back.

Take a look at login route in api.php this one is for sure not working but was working before I started using Homestead and vagrant.

Any ideas ? Here are my interresting configurations about API and routes (Hosted files on github) :

1) [RouteServiceProvider.php](https://github.com/Keldarne/ldap-laravel-test/blob/master/RouteServiceProvider.php)

2) [api.php](https://github.com/Keldarne/ldap-laravel-test/blob/master/api.php)

3) [Kernel.php](https://github.com/Keldarne/ldap-laravel-test/blob/master/Kernel.php)

Can't understand why ! If needed I can upload full project but I can't stand why it doesn't work since start of the week.

Please be kind with me this is my first project with Laravel.

Kind regards

Edit : Just added php artisan route:list --path:foobar result :

[route-list-ouptut](https://github.com/Keldarne/ldap-laravel-test/blob/master/route-list-result)

Comment: please add to answer output of `php artisan route:list`. May be to even filter example that is not working, with `php artisan route:list --path=foobar`

Comment: @PetrReshetin just added route-list-output in my post, just want you to notice that my login route in now in Route::any() mode so I could test more things but post doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine, except I would remove these lines from `api.php`:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, Authorization');
```

As I understand these are request headers. So you should add the in your Postman request headers (or another Rest client). And not in any where in your code.

If you want to add headers to response, rather then request here are [Laravel Create Response Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#creating-responses)

Comment: This was solution I didn't think that changing headers like this would cause problems with Post routes.